# change of address (webmaster Tools)

Tags: http-status-code-301, google-search-console

I've got a problem with Google's Change of Address function on the Google Webmaster tools returning "301 redirect failed".

I had a website at domainA, and as part of re branding have recently moved to a new domain - domainB.
Anything at domainA is set to 301 redirect to domainB.

When I go to webmaster tools for domainA, and set a change of address to domainB, I get the following message:
301 redirect failed. We detect that the root address of your old site (domainA) does not yet redirect to the root address of your new site (domainB). For more information use the Fetch as Google tool.

The fetch as google tool shows the status of "/" as Redirected to domainB.

The only thing I can think of which may be causing an issue is that the root of domainB "/" is set to redirect to domainB/home because of an issue with the CMS system.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why webmaster tools is not allowing me to complete the change of address?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the redirect of site root to /home was causing the issue.

I created an index.html page from the source of "/home" on domianB, added a canonical tag, and disabled the root redirect.

The change of address submission then worked.